# How to get a String Resourse in Android having no Context?

Tags: android, resources, android-context

I wrote java class which extends BaseObservable to use it as ViewModel in MVVM and I need to get a String resourse. Usual getString() doesn't work because I had no Context and I tried this

`String toFormat = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.playbackSpeedText);`

I got android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException from it. I resolved my problem adding a Context field to class constructor but I'm interested if I could get String resourse by another way using no Context.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to create getResource(int id) abstract method inside common navigator of your activity
and implement it in activity or baseactivity where you can return the resource.getstring(with uniqueId)

and then call it from your viewmodel and get string by using the
`navigator.getResource(R.string.alertmessage)`

Another way In applicationclass

```
Applicationclassname instance;

oncreate(){
  Instance = this
}
```

create static getInstance() method for  singleton synchronized object of application class and return instance object from here

Then

```
Applicationclass.getInstance().getString(R.string.alertmessage)
```

anywhere by using application class instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AndroidViewModel instead of ViewModel
or
if you are using dagger2 or hilt you can create a model that injects application context where you can get string

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `string resource` by implementing this code

```java
public class SomeViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final String toFormat;

    public SomeViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        toFormat = application.getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.playbackSpeedText);
    }

    public final String getToFormat() {
        return this.toFormat;
    }


}
```